# Python - Looking for a solution to prevent duplicates in lists generated via text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

As the title mentions, I'm looking for a way for my code to not only detect duplicates in a list, but to separate the items, moving them to other lists.

I am relatively new at programming, having just finished an introductory course to python at my local JC. During the course of the semester, I had an idea to create a program that would read lines in a .txt file, place them in a list, shuffle the list, and split the single list into two new lists before printing them. This would be used for quickly distributing uniquely named objects to two players in a game, for example. Here is what the code looks like so far:

Given that list.txt = apple, apple, banana, pear, orange, kiwi

```
import random
#create list from text file
list = [line.strip() for line in open("list.txt", 'r')]

#Copy list to preserve the original
list2 = list[::]
random.shuffle(list2) #shuffle the order

#If # of items = odd, remove one
if len(list2) % 2 == 1:
    del list2[-1]

#Divide items into two lists
A = list2[:len(list2)//2]
B = list2[len(list2)//2:]

print("The items in group A are: ", A)
print("The items in group B are: ", B)
```

I've gotten everything to work so far, but something I want to implement is having the program detect if, say, both "apple"'s are in list A and, if they are, move one to list B. I've come up with three solutions, but not one of them works. Solution 1 would be to take the two "apple"'s as they are and detect/sort from there.

```
def moveDuplicates(in_list):
    unique = set(in_list)
    for each in unique:
        count = in_list.count(each)
        if count > 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

The problem is that I can detect duplicates just fine like this, but I don't know how to specify moving one of them since I won't know the position of either in the new lists, since it's shuffled every time.

Solution 2 is to rename the "apple"s to apple1 and apple2, or something similar. With this solution, I can choose to delete and append either item easily, but I don't know how to get the program to detect that two items with sequential numbers are in the same list.

Solution 3 is the worst one imo, since it involves writing conditions for every potential duplicate to make sure before the shuffle that one of each would be placed in each list, which violates DRY principles.

I feel that the most ideal solution would be to use solution 2 or 3 while somehow using something similar to how google uses asterisks in searches to denote that anything can be in place of the asterisk.

Comment: could possibly use something like `collections.Counter`, not sure what you are trying to do though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming if you have more than 2 copies of any word, you can ignore everything after the first two. My suggested solution splits the list into repeated values, which will be shared by both groups and single values, which will be shuffled and split among the two groups.

```
import collections

list = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd']

# Split the list into words that occur once and ones that are repeats
single = []
repeats = []
for word, count in collections.Counter(list).items():
    if count > 1:
        repeats.append(word)
    else:
        single.append(word)

# Each group gets a copy of the repeats
group_a = repeats[:]
group_b = repeats[:]

# Now shuffle/divide the single values
random.shuffle(single)
half = len(single) // 2
group_a.extend(single[:half])
group_b.extend(single[half:2*half])
```

You could add additional shuffles for the individual groups, if you like.

Comment: Looks pretty perfect to me.

Comment: Might I suggest simply `single[half:]` rather than `single[half:2*half]` or else the last item when single has odd length will be omitted.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga At first I was agreeing with you, but then I noticed that single[half:2*half] rather brilliantly takes care of the condition I had in case there were an odd number of items, and since it does it after the shuffle, it's still random. It works rather well!

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a way to use the equivalent of an asterisk like one would when searching (like *.txt for a file browser)?

Comment: @Erin.Signe I'm not sure I follow. How would the asterisk be used?

Comment: @xulfir In file browsers, for example, searching something like '*.txt' will return all files with the .txt extension.  In Python, I would like to know if a similar option is available. If, for example, I wanted to remove all values in a list that had something before the number 2, I could write `del list1[*2]`.

Answer (score 0):

How about just to use simple for-cycle? I will try to make it simple for you. If I understood your idea correctly then it can be implemented like this:

```
# Some input into this example 
fruits = ["apple", "apple", "banana", "pear", "orange", "kiwi"]

# The code you're probably looking for
first_basket = []
second_basket = []

for fruit in fruits:
    if fruit not in first_basket:
         first_basket.append(fruit)
    elif fruit not in second_basket:
         second_basket.append(fruit)

print first_basket
print second_basket
```

So, if your first basket not contains fruit from fruits, it will be added to first_basket. Else if your second basket not contains fruit, it will be added to second_basket. So if both baskets already have fruit from your list it won't be added to any basket.

This example will print ["apple", "banana", "pear", "orange", "kiwi"] (this is your first_basket) and then ["apple"] (this is your second_basket).

Comment: OP wants to equally and randomly distribute the items into two lists, while also avoiding dupes in the resulting lists. You got the last part but missed the main focus of the question.